# Apache BeanUtils behavioral conflict while copying List items from different classes

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am developing an application that copy data of one class to another class.

I am trying to test `getter-setter` method works fine or not. To improve `test coverage` I am making some class and methods that will use `podamfactory` to fill up data inside given class's members.

Then I am copying data of that object to other object using `apache BeanUtils`.

Then I am asserting both objects to check that both have same data or not !

The problem I am facing that:
I have create 3 classes:

> 1. Starter.java [have main method to run application]
> 2. ChildClass.java [have only 1 member i.e. Collection of String and it's getter method and add method to add data inside that member]
> 3. ParentClass.java [inside this class ChildClass's instance have been created and instantiated and related getter and setter method. Also have hashcode and equals method]

Code:

```
public class Starter {

    static final PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start");
        testClasses(ParentClass.class);
        System.out.println("End");
    }

    public static void testClasses(final Class<?> klass) throws Exception {
        final Object source = factory.manufacturePojo(klass);
        final Object destination = klass.newInstance();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(destination, source);
        Assert.assertEquals(source, destination);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(source, new Object());
        Assert.assertEquals(source.hashCode(), destination.hashCode());
    }
}
```

In `Main` method I am passing `ParentClass` to check it's getter setter. `testClasses` method do the main work of copy and `assertion`.

When I am debugging I found that after `copying properties` of class, child class's instance have list and that have 5 members. In both object there's 5 members in `List` element.

**But** When I am passing `ChildClass` in `Main` then try to debug I am getting `5 element` in `source` and in `destination` class it have `0 element` after `copying properties`.

So I don't understand this behavior of `BeanUtils`, what need to do If I want same work when I am passing `ChildClass` in `Main` ?

When I am passing `ParentClass` it's have different behavior and when I am passing `ChildClass` it have different behavior in `Copying properties`.

I have created [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/keyurbhatt/BeanUtilTest) to show my code. You can access and check code of my application.

I have created simple `gradle` project for `dependency management`.

If anyone knows more about it then let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a beanutils question not a Podam question. I'd suggest you remove the jemos-podam tag. Podam is behaving as expected, i.e. it fills your member attributes with values.

Answer (score 0):

BeanUtils follows strict definition of properties in Java Bean sense, i.e. each property must have getter with name *get* + name of a field and setter with name *set* + name of a field. While your child class contains no setFields() setter. In other words you could change it like this

```
public class ChildClass {

    private final List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getFields() {
        return this.fields;
    }

    public List<String> setFields(List<String> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }
}
```

or alternatively

```
public class ChildClass {

    private final List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getFields() {
        return this.fields;
    }

    public List<String> setFields(List<String> fields) {
        this.fields.clear();
        this.fields.addAll(fields);
    }
}
```